# Use SceneKit to fix a model and output the result

Tags: scenekit

I'm trying to use SceneKit to correct a model made up of multiple pieces, flatten it, and write it out to a file again. I assume Model I/O is involved. Is it possible to output an SCNNode to a Wavefront OBJ or Collada file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create an MDLObject from SCNNode

After creating the object you can then add it to an asset and export.

```
let object = MDLObject(SCNNode: flattenedNode)

let modelAsset = MDLAsset()
modelAsset.addObject(modelHeart)
modelAsset.exportAssetToURL(NSURL(string: "file://somewhere/file.obj"))
```